# how to make virtualenv see the default python version on Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, virtualenv, ubuntu-16.04

I encounter an error when creating virtual environment on Ubuntu-16.04.
In particular, `virtualenv -p python myenv` returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 7, in <module>
    from virtualenv.__main__ import run_with_catch
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/virtualenv/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .run import cli_run, session_via_cli
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/virtualenv/run/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ..app_data import make_app_data
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/virtualenv/app_data/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from platformdirs import user_data_dir
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/platformdirs/__init__.py", line 29
    result: type[PlatformDirsABC] = getattr(importlib.import_module(module), name)
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

meaning incorrect syntax in Python 3.5. However, I have set my default python version on Ubuntu to be Python 3.8.9 i.e., `python -V` returns `Python 3.8.9`.
So why does `virtualenv` refer to Python 3.5 even though Python 3.8.9 is default?

Additional info:
My `virtualenv` version is 15.0.1
The first line in the traceback refers to `/usr/local/bin/virtualenv`, which looks like this

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from virtualenv.__main__ import run_with_catch

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(run_with_catch())
```

Update:
Running `python3 -m pip install virtualenv`
returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 185, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 144, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip.locations import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/locations.py", line 9, in <module>
    from distutils import sysconfig
ImportError: cannot import name 'sysconfig' from 'distutils' (/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/__init__.py)
```

Comment: 1) you can set `python` path in `.profile` (or .bashrc etc) to point to whatever python you want  2) you could provide complete python-3.8 path to the command `virtualenv -p /path/to/py3.8 myenv`

Comment: @muon 1) after adding `python=/usr/bin/python3.8 running` to `.profile`  and also 2) when running `virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.8 myenv` I keep getting exactly the same error :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the below command for ensuring that virtualenv refers to  python3.8 by default

```
python3.8 -m virtualenv myenv
```

Comment: No, exactly the same error is returned

Comment: @Python Can you try to update the version of virtualenv and see if it helps?

Comment: Sure. Running `sudo apt install --upgrade virtualenv` returns `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
virtualenv is already the newest version (15.0.1+ds-3ubuntu1.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`
And the error does not change

Comment: @Python Could you try to update virtualenv with this command `python3 -m pip install virtualenv`?

Comment: Yes, but I obtain an error during the update (see updated above)

Comment: @Python Can you try to install distutils using this command `sudo apt install python3.8-distutils`

Comment: I guess I will have to remove my Ubuntu now and start everything from the scratch, because now I keep receiving very strange errors. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @Python Glad to help. Could you please mark my answer as accepted if it helped?

Answer (score 0):

When I encountered the same error in Ubuntu 16.04,  I upgraded my python package although when I used:

```
python --version
```

it showed version 3.8. I then upgraded and reinstalled my Python package version 3.8 with the code below:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt install python3.8
```

I then proceeded to create a new virtual environment using:

```
python3.8 -m venv -m venv name_of_the_project_env
```

I then activated the environment with:

```
source name_of_the_project_env/bin/activate
```

and this solved my problem.